# iOS 7.1 issue - Tabbar resizing doesn't work

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, tabs

Since i updated to iOS 7.1 the resizing of the tab (to 74 pixels) that doesn't work anymore:

```
[[tabBarController.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, screenSize.height-73)];
[tabBarController.tabBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, screenSize.height-73, 320, 74)];
```

This code results in the tab being moved up, but with some empty space bellow.

As anyone a fix for that ?

Comment: I guess the views hierarchy was modified, and you are not accessing the needed object. This is happening because your approach is poor and not sure if it's even allowed. When you iterate thru subviews, you must do some checks to ensure that you've got the right one.

Comment: indeed if I loop "[tabBarController.view subviews]" i get the same views on both devices: UITransitionView and then UITabBar. What approach do you suggest ?

Comment: I can resize the tabBar in ``viewWillAppear``, but if I hide the tabBar when pushing a VC and then hit back again, the bar gets resized to default again.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you change the size of your `UITabBar` in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` of your `UITabBarController` subclass, the resizing works under iOS 7 and 7.1. Take my code as an example:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
     CGFloat tabBarHeight = 39.0;
     CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
     self.tabBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, frame.size.height - tabBarHeight, frame.size.width, tabBarHeight);
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Worked for me.

Comment: I use UITabBar as a rightBarButtonItem of UINavigationItems. Wrapping a UITabBar with a custom UIView subclass, and use it as the customView of the UIBarButtonItem. Overriding `-[UIView layoutSubviews]` of the customView like the answer help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

this is what i currently use, I have removed the image from the tab bar, then i added this bit of code to position the text, I think the second line is obsolete but i keep it anyway. the for statement places your text in the bar, so u can adjust modifying the -25 value, 30 being the size of my tab bar height. The rest of the bar is technically "hidden" under the screen.

```
self.tabBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, screenHeight - 30,  screenWidth, 30);
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, screenHeight - 30,  screenWidth, 30);

for (int i = 0; i < self.tabBar.items.count; i++)
{
    [[self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:i] setTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, -25)];
}
```